# How to load two sheets at once with xlsread

Tags: matlab

I currently have this code to load a set of prompts to assign the appropriate data:

```
full=xlsread(input('File Name for Full data?\n'),input('Sheet Name for full?\n'));
empty=xlsread(input('File Name for Empty data?\n'),input('Sheet Name for empty?\n'));

xx1=full(:,1);
yy1=full(:,2);
ff1=full(:,3);
xx2=empty(:,1);
yy2=empty(:,2);
ff2=empty(:,3);
```

However, since the full and empty sheets are both in one spreadsheet, I would like to make it so that there is only one prompt for the file and then a prompt for each sheet, so something like:

```
everything=xlsread(input('File Name for Full data?\n'),input('Sheet Name for full?\n'),input('Sheet Name for empty?\n');
xx1=everything(:,1);
yy1=everything(:,2);
ff1=everything(:,3);
xx2=everything(:,4);
yy2=everything(:,5);
ff2=everything(:,6);
```

What can I do to make this work out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the `input` calls before you use `xlsread`

```
filename = input('File Name for Full data?\n')
full = input('Sheet Name for full?\n')
empty = input('Sheet Name for empty?\n')

full=xlsread(filename, full);
empty=xlsread(filename, empty);

xx1=full(:,1);
yy1=full(:,2);
ff1=full(:,3);
xx2=empty(:,1);
yy2=empty(:,2);
ff2=empty(:,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though `xlsread` does not support this directly, you can create a wrapper that will call `xlsread` in the right way.

Basically just ask the input arguments that you need, and based on them make a call to `xlsread`.

---

It is indeed a weakness that you cannot read multiple sheets simultaneously, but xlsread is just a very basic command. Personally I think it is a greater weakness that you can only read out contiguous ranges.